# Intuitive or physical explanation of DTFT$\{1\}=2\pi\delta(\omega)$

Tags: discrete-signals, infinite-impulse-response, dtft, dirac-delta-impulse

I am trying to understand the fact that

"The DTFT of 1 (an infinite discrete sequence of unit impulses from from $-\infty$  to $+\infty$) is $2\pi\delta(\omega)$"

in an intuitive or physical manner so that the significance of this result and its application in signal processing is understood.

just to show how the above result is obtained ( in a rather indirect manner )

the IDFT of $2\cdot\pi\cdot\delta(\omega) is = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} 2\cdot\pi\cdot\delta(\omega)\cdot e^{{j\omega n}}d\omega$

now , $\delta(\omega)$ is defined for $\omega=0 $ and is $=1$ , and $0$ everywhere else. The $R.H.S$ works out to $1$.

so ,the DTFT of 1 is $2\cdot\pi\cdot\delta(\omega)$.

What does the above statement mean physically/intuitively ? , that the only frequency component of the signal ( an infinite discrete sequence of unit impulses from from $  -\infty to +\infty$) is an impulse of magnitude of $2\cdot\pi$ at $\omega = 0$. So is it being interpreted as a zero frequency (DC component)  signal with an average magnitude of $2\cdot\pi$.

Where does the magnitude $2\cdot\pi$  come from ?.

Am I right or missing something here ? - Thanks.

Comment: If it were me, I would say that $$ \mathrm{DTFT}\big\{ x[n]=1 \big\} = 2 \pi \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\omega - 2\pi k) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that an infinitely long constant sequence has just one frequency component at DC. That's why its spectrum must be concentrated at DC and must be zero for all $\omega\neq 0$.

Note that the Dirac delta impulse $\delta(\omega)$ is zero for all $\omega\neq 0$, but it doesn't make sense to talk about its value at $\omega=0$, because $\delta(\omega)$ is not a conventional function but a generalized function, also called a distribution. For your intuition, you might want to think about $\delta(\omega)$ being infinite at $\omega=0$, but definitely not equal to $1$ as you've mentioned in your question. It is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) that equals $1$ for zero argument, but that's totally different from the Dirac delta impulse. The latter only makes sense under an integral, and the property that you need to know is (assuming $a<b$):

$$\int_a^bf(x)\delta(x)dx=\begin{cases}f(0),& a<0<b\\0,&\textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

provided that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.

The factor $2\pi$ in the transform of a constant value is a consequence of dealing with angular frequency $\omega=2\pi f$. If you used $f$ instead you would get rid of that scaling factor:

$$\textrm{DTFT}\{1\}=\delta(f)$$

Comment: You might want to add, for the sake of completeness, that the integral  that you have written has value $f(0)$ provided that $f(x)$ is _continuous_ at $x=0$.  It doesn't matter for the application here since $f(x)=1 \forall x$ is continuous everywhere including at $x=0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Yes, added.